# Perl - Use lib with perl module which have dependencies

Tags: perl, ssh, perl-module

I have a Perl script which uses the module [`Net::SSH::Any`](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SSH-Any-0.01/lib/Net/SSH/Any.pm). Since it does not belong to the “default” Perl installation, I have to use the `use lib` functionality to include it in my script.

Now, I have the directory `c:\lib\net\ssh\any\` on my drive and I specify this: `use lib c:/lib;` at the beginning of my script.

It “works”: it didn’t say that the module is missing but it says that it couldn’t locate `auto/Net/SSH2/autosplit.ix` and at the end `no backend available at...`

When I add the `auto` directory (containing the correct structure) in the `c:\lib\` directory and launch the script, I get this error:

```
No backend available at...
```

Which is an internal error of Net::SSH::Any mentioning it could not access the backend directory (which is already included :/)

Does anyone know how to solve something like that? I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: Can't you install the module normally with the `cpan` program?

Comment: Have you installed `Net::SSH2` or `Net::OpenSSH`? One of both seems to be a hard prereq for the `Any` module.

Comment: Net::SSH2 requires the libssh2 library which, IIRC, requires the openssl library. Check that you can load Net::SSH2: `perl -Ic:\lib -MNet::SSH2 -e1`. Otherwise try using some tool as `procmon` to find out why it is failing.

Comment: Thanks Salva! Your command seems to say that the SSH2.dll file cannot be loaded. May be it's due to an incompatibility of my windows (modules downloaded and installed on my old xp 32 bits computer but server is 64 bits based)
I'll re-install it with the "exact" same configuration and get back to you! Thanks

Comment: It works, I put the "how to solve" as a post response. Thanks for your help and tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the fact that the module was downloaded and installed on a 32bits windows but I tried to run it on a perl 64bits installation! So the Net::SSH2 required module couldn't be executed properly.

To resume:

-How to detect the issue: by executing this command: (thanks to Salva)
"perl -Ic:\lib -MNet::SSH2 -e1"

-Modules definitions in my script:
`use lib 'c:\lib';`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Local::Lib](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?local%3A%3Alib).
This will let you install and load a whole bunch of libraries and their dependencies in an alternate location. I use cpanm to manage my modules and a command something like this (which I put in a wrapper script).

```
cpanm -L $cpandir $M --no-skip-installed
```

Where `$cpandir` is your locallibdir and `$M` is the module you are trying to install.

Then in your code you would specify

```
use local::lib '~/foo';
```

However, I recommend setting a `PERL5LIB` environment variable, which will append your custom location to `@INC` and make the extra use local::lib line unnecessary. You would typically edit `.bashrc` or `.profile` in your home directory with a line like:

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/myusername/mymods/
```

Comment: Brainbuz, thanks for your reply. Actually, PERL5LIB works in the "same way" than "use lib". PERL5LIB is just a environment variable outside the script. I tried with it but the result is the same.
Otherwise, the usage of this "trick" is because I can NOT use the package manager. I don't have any access to the internet from the involved server and I have not the permission to modify the standard perl package of my company. That's why I've to add the module in another location only for this server.

Comment: I have a similar situation -- I install the modules to an alternate location on a server with the same OS and architecture with Internet access, then use tar and scp to copy the directory to the target server.

Comment: Its been a while since I've dealt with Perl on Windows, you have 3 issues to work through -- getting local lib to work (which I would do some testing to make sure that it is working, and that the problem is somewhere else), issues with the modules themselves, issues with the windows environment and the specific windows perl you're using that are impacting your scripts.

Comment: I'm more or less already like that I think. I've made the dev of the script on my local computer with my "official company build of perl" + the Net::SSH::Any module and it's working. The "single" difference is that on my computer, the environment variable is set by perl and I don't have to deal with PERL5LIB or use lib functionality. I've tried to put my entire perl folder from my computer to the server but result is the same